# How to write a while loop into a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, while-loop

My code looks like:

```
x=0
while (x<3):
    print('purple'),
    print('yellow'),
    print({x})
    x=x+1
```

I want it to log this data into a csv file named 'daffodils.csv'.
How do I do this so that the iterations won't write over eachother?

For example, if I ran the program two times, my csv file will look like:

```
purple yellow 0
purple yellow 1
purple yellow 2
purple yellow 0
purple yellow 1
purple yellow 2
```

Thanks

Comment: FYI: That is not a valid csv file (unless it's a single column).

Comment: `print({x})` creates and prints a *set* containing `x`, is that really what you want?

Comment: It sounds like the words in the question are asking [How do you append to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file) but the code blocks don't seem to have any relation to file io...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply use:

```
t = open("daffodils.csv", "a+")
x=0
while (x<3):
    t.write('purple'),
    t.write('yellow'),
    t.write({x})
    t.write("\n")
    x=x+1
t.close()
```

The `a` opens the file in append mode, and the `+` creates it if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: `.append`? That will be an `AttributeError`

Comment: Jammy, you might want to test that program before posting.

Comment: Oh sorry, wasn't concentrating, let me just edit it

Answer (score 1):

Simply use,

```
with open('test.txt', 'a') as f:
    for x in range(3):
        s = 'purple yellow {}\n'.format(x)
        f.write(s)
```

---

Or use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) as you want,

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
    for x in range(3):
        writer.writerow(['purple', 'yellow', x])
```

Comment: `for x in range(3):` removes the need to set the default, while and increment.

Comment: @TemporalWolf, thx. just edited.